# flesh-humans meta tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-tag

I just noticed the [flesh-humans](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flesh-humans). This is (in my opinion) a redundant meta-tag and is being used to indicate that humans are in fact human. As far as I am aware, if humans deviate from being entirely human by being virtual or cyborgs, then it is indicated in the question.

Even if there is a case for creating a virtual-humans or other non-normative human tag, humans being humans is normative and should not have a tag. Anyone agree/disagree?

Comment: The tag is currently used on exactly two questions. It has also been used only by a single user on the site. If we're going to get rid of it, it's a lot less disruptive doing so now than if we wait until it is attached to 50 questions!

Comment: Burn it, I don't care. If I were creating it today, I'd probably call it "unaugumented humans" or something like that. But I was young and foolish back then. Let it burn, if that is the will of the Mods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag has been replaced with [humans](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humans) on both questions where it appeared. This change should propagate fully throughout the site within the next 24 hours or so.

Comment: Thanks for handling this before I even knew it was a problem.  Nice job, UTC+X mods! :-)

Answer (score 6):

I can see how the tag might be useful in cases where you want to be clear the answers should not use cybernetics etc. However Flesh Humans is ambiguous too though as things like mutants, bio engineering, etc could be very different from humans as we know it but still flesh-humans. For that matter if you start implanting chips in people's skulls where does the line between flesh-humans and cyborgs get drawn?

So in other words, I agree - the tag can be burninated :)

Comment: Trogdor strikes again.

Comment: I agree.  If we need to differentiate between humans as we know them today and cyborg humans, brain-in-a-jar humans, asceending-to-the-spirit-plane humans, or something else, *those* special cases can get new tags.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Emphasis *need*.